# ような without a noun following it

Tags: grammar

> いつからか、翡翠がやってくれば平穏な朝を迎えられる**ような**、そんな日課が出来上がっている。

Why is ような used before the comma?

I think it means:

> Since who knows when, if Hisui comes, as if i am brought with a
> tranquil morning, that way the day starts.

But I do not understand why ような is used before the comma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There certainly is a noun following 「～～ような」, if the noun does not ***directly*** follow it.  That noun is 「[日課]{にっか}」.

> 「いつからか、[翡翠]{ひすい}がやってくれば[平穏]{へいおん}な[朝]{あさ}を[迎]{むか}えられるような、そんな日課が[出来上]{できあ}がっている。」

「翡翠がやってくれば平穏な朝を迎えられるような」 is an adjectival phrase that modifies 「日課」.

「そんな」 also modifies 「日課」.

「そんな」 here means "that sort of".  The author could have just said 「翡翠がやってくれば平穏な朝を迎えられる**ような日課**」 without using 「、そんな」.

「翡翠がやってくれば平穏な朝を迎えられるような」, however, is such a ***long and eloquent*** adjectival phrase that it could sound a little "affected" if the author placed 「日課」 directly following it.

By placing 「、そんな」(= "that sort of"), it could serve as a softener that brings the eloquence level down a bit.

My shot at a TL:

"Since who knows when, a sort of a daily routine has been formed in which I feel as if I could greet the dawn peacefully whenever Hisui comes/is here."

Comment: Perfect.
I also tought it could modify 日課.
I tought 迎むかえられる was passive and not a potential though, and that really messed up my understanding.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm a native speaker and I'm still not actually not sure… ☺

Although, Japanese sentences sometimes have the verb after the noun, although that might be a bit of a stretch. I believe if a predicate has 
a "、" or "を" after it, it is forming a compound sentence. I am still not sure… But I think it's a sentence structure quirk.

Hope I was able to help.